# YAMLLOADWARNING when use ccm in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, bigdata, ccm

when I use the 'ccm start' command, I encounter the following warning ! 
Why this error occurs ؟‌

/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccmlib/cluster_factory.py:22: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.

/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccmlib/node.py:143: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  data = yaml.load(f)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should note the difference between a warning and an error. A warning, as it is in this case, usually does not prevent the action from being completed. So this is just a warning, not an error. And if you read the message you can see the key word: "deprecated". So this is why. The default loader is considered unsafe, that's why it is deprecated.